# Ng-bind does not update value after change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a new in AngularJS and cannot understand something
In this code:
View:

```
  <div ng-controller="ordersCtrl">
            <div id="messagesIndic" onclick="messageClick()" class="btn btn-info">
                Messages <span class="badge badge-primary" ng-bind="orders.length"></span>

            </div>
        </div>

...


<div ng-controller="ordersCtrl">

            <div ng-repeat="order in orders track by $index" class="order-page">
                <div class="orders-list-content">
                    <div style="margin:2px">Cource name: {{order.Title}}</div>
                    <div style="margin:2px">Description: {{order.Description}}</div>
                    <div style="margin:2px">Teacher name: {{order.TeacherName}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="orders-list-buttons" style="text-align:center">
                    <div class="order-button btn btn-success" ng-click="successOrder(order.Id)">Success</div>
                    <div class="order-button btn btn-danger" ng-click="rejectOrder(order.Id )">Reject</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And JS code:

```
    app.controller('ordersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.ordersLen = 0;
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/Course/OrdersToCource"
        }).then(function (result) {
            $scope.orders = result.data
        })

        $scope.successOrder = function (id, item, eventCaller) {
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/Cource/SuccessToOrder?orderId=" + id
            }).then(function (result) {
                var index = $scope.orders.indexOf(item);
                console.log(item);
                $scope.orders.splice(index, 1);
                $scope.ordersLen = $scope.orders.length
            })
        }

        $scope.rejectOrder = function (id, item, eventCaller) {
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/Course/RejectOrderToCourse?orderId=" + id
            }).then(function (result) {
                var index = $scope.orders.indexOf(item);
                $scope.orders.splice(index, 1);
            })
        }
    })
```

When I am init **rejectOrder** or **successOrder** functions it works successfully and after response from server it remove element from "orders" array and binded to ***ng-repeat*** model dynamically hide removed element BUT ***ng-bind="orders.length"*** does not change. Did some have any idea what is a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason, I have two controllers with same name but - notwithstanding each other have his own $scope

Answer (score 2):

`ng-bind` doesn't work with array because you are changing values of array outside of digest cycle. Either use `$scope.apply()` or you can try just using double curly markup `{{orders.length}}` within your `span` tag, that should do the trick.

```
<div id="messagesIndic" onclick="messageClick()" class="btn btn-info">
                Messages <span class="badge badge-primary">{{orders.length}}</span>

            </div>
```

Comment: It did not help (

Comment: Ok, Can you please add a http://jsfiddle.net or https://plnkr.co/ example of your code so that I can provide solution there?